# Image Capture Intent makes image file different permission

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I'm trying to give the user the option to either supply a photo they've taken in the past, or take a new photo right now. The issue is that when I try to use the image, I get a "permission denied."

This is where I make the chooser intent:

```
final File root = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "MyDir" + File.separator);
root.mkdirs();
final String fname = "img_" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg";
outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(new File(root, fname));

Intent takePhotoIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE_SECURE);
takePhotoIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri);
Intent pickPhotoIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
pickPhotoIntent.setType("image/*");

Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(pickPhotoIntent, "Take a photo or select one from your device");
chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, new Intent[] {takePhotoIntent});

startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, 1);
```

outputFileUri is a field variable in the class. I use that to load an image as so:

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
     /...
     String url = selectedImageUri.toString();
     final Bitmap image = Picasso.with(context).load(url).get();
```

And I get an error as follows:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/MyDir/img_1466710420779.jpg: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
```

This used to work when I had it in an Activity class, but I converted that to a Fragment class and it stopped working (I changed nothing else - all I did was make it a fragment).

Anyone have ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: It sounds that you are missing your activity instance in your fragment. Other than that, start monitoring with logs the folder and see what's in it.

Comment: What do you mean "missing your activity instance in your fragment"? Should I be using the activity to do something?

Comment: i.e. getActivity().startActivity(...) or pass that instance from Activity to Fragment

Comment: Oh, I tried doing getActivity().startActivityForResult(...) and then passing the parameters from the activity's onActivityResult(...) method to the fragment's onActivityResult(...) method. I had the same exact issue so I just went back to doing it via the fragment's startActivityForResult(...)

Comment: Fragment Life cycle does not contain onActivityResult. https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Lifecycle. So, I believe somewhere there must be the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe problem is in .startActivityForResult() method. There is no .onActivityResult () method in you code

Comment: That second code segment is in the onActivityResult